# Start a background Service and cause Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary: Indicated size is invalid

Tags: flutter, dart

I just upgrade `flutter` to the latest version,`flutter doctor -v` complains no error.Error part of the log output when installing apk from   `Android Studio` looks like this:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
E/flutter (24489): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(197)] Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary: Indicated size is invalid.
E/flutter (24489): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(198)] Could not prepare to run the isolate.
E/flutter (24489): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(137)] Engine not prepare and launch isolate.
E/flutter (24489): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(433)] Could not launch engine with configuration.

I/zygote64(24489): Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=87KB
I/zygote64(24489): After code cache collection, code=116KB, data=66KB
```

I have tried to delete `flutter` `bin/cache` suggested by a [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21810), and `flutter doctor` again, but this cannot solve `Dart Error:Invalid kernel binary: Indicated size is invalid` problem.
And my `flutter channel` is in `master` **not** `stable`.
By the way,this `does always` happens,when the first attempt to run fails, the second attempt to run can bypass those errors,just cannot figure it out why.

#### First Edit

There is so little information on `Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary: Indicated size is invalid`.It's not a problem on `kernel format`,but a problem on `kernel size`,is there a place to tweak configuration of flutter Dart engine?

#### Second Edit

<strike>Here is my `pubspec.yaml`</strike>

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  intl: ^0.15.7
  provider: ^3.1.0
  shrine_images: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: 5.1.0
  path_provider: ^1.2.0
  barcode_scan: ^1.0.0
  qr_flutter: ^1.1.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  flutter_circular_slider: ^2.5.0
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  after_layout: ^1.0.7+2
  wave:


  crypto: ^2.1.2
  rxdart: ^0.22.2

  bloc: ^0.15.0
  flutter_bloc: ^0.21.0
  equatable: ^0.2.0
  json_serializable: ^3.2.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.4
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3

  encrypt: ^3.3.1
  connectivity: ^0.4.4
  animator: ^1.0.0+1

  imei_plugin: ^1.1.4
  photo_view: ^0.7.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  pedantic: ^1.4.0
  build_runner: ^1.6.9
```

The apk **can** be installed when I push `Run` button twice in `Android Studio` interface to bypass error I've mentioned above, but that apk cannot work properly when I distributed it to others, it just pops out a white screen with nothing else.

#### Third Edit

<strike>I also involved a discussion in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44161).</strike>

#### Fourth Edit

I have created a minimum [project](https://github.com/ZionPi/bdary.git) to reproduce issues here(for the time being only `android platform` is concerned),and also open a new flutter [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46149).

#### Fifth Edit

As I reference a third party's library which is different from `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to provide background push notification service.
I suppose `Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary: Indicated size is invalid.`  is caused by that service.As I commented out the line which start it, no errors displayed.Minimum [project](https://github.com/ZionPi/bdary.git) to reproduce this issue also has been updated accordingly.

Comment: Can you share the output of `flutter doctor -v` command? And also post here please your pubspec.yaml. The error appears only on master channel?

Comment: @dubace I'm glad to have your response, but `flutter doctor -v` shows no `big` error as I've described  above.Maybe I'll put up my `pubspec.yaml` later which I don't think it is related.

Comment: Try running `flutter clean`. This should automatically clear the cache. I had a similar issue, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved this via remove the cache folder and install flutter again.

```sh
rm -rf ${FLUTTER_ROOT}/bin/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following steps resolved the problem:

1- Open cmd and run flutter doctor. (if there is an issue resolve them first.)

2- If not then change the flutter channel to dev. Whatever your channel is?. If this is the dev channel then change to master channel.

3- Again flutter doctor. If everything goes perfectly. then run your project. If it runs accordingly then again change to channel to stable.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me, this was what I did:

1. Just delete the current Flutter version you have (I was using Flutter 3.13.1). I deleted that and downloaded the latest version (at the time Flutter 3.13.7)
2. Update your environmental variables to the path of the extracted flutter.
3. Run `flutter doctor` to verify everything works fine
4. Run `flutter pub get` on your project to update your dependencies.